# PHP5.5 Exec and Taskkill

Tags: php, exec, taskkill

I want to write a little internal Interface for my windows server 2012 with PHP 5.5. Now i have a list of tasks via tasklist where i get a list of pids that should be killed.

My Problem is that i can't kill any task. exec(Taskkill /F /PID xxx) is not working. I searched in the internet and read often, that the safemode is the problem. But under PHP 5.5 there is no safe_mode options anymore.

How can i use taskkill oder functions for starting programs or is there no ability to do that anymore?

Comment: do you get an error when you use passthru?

Comment: I don't find an error and no output. But taskkill is not working...